# Customize standalone AIR runtime folder package

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flashdevelop

I'm looking to figure out if there is a way to customize the folder structure when packaging an AIR app with the captive runtime?

As it is right now the folder structure is as follows:

Projectname_standalone [**parrentfolder**]

- Adobe AIR [**folder**]
- META-INF [**folder**]
- other folders for images and such [**folder**]
- mimetype [**file** in Projectname_standalone folder]
- projectname.exe [**file** in Projectname_standalone folder]
- projectname.swf [**file** in Projectname_standalone folder]

What i would like to get is something along the lines with this:

Projectname_standalone [**parrentfolder**]

- data [**folder**]
- - Adobe AIR [**subfolder** of data]
- - META-INF [**subfolder** of data]
- - other folders for images and such [**subfolder** of data]
- - mimetype [**file** in data folder]
- projectname.exe [**file** in Projectname_standalone folder]
- projectname.swf [**file** in Projectname_standalone folder]

Has anyone any experience with this?I'm working in Flashdevelop, but I assume this would also apply to both Flash Pro and Flash Builder and include some modification of the AIR SDK.

Comment: why are you concerned with this? The app folder should not be of any concern for you and you should have no business messing with it.

Comment: I had need to put it on our company server, and to be able to hide the content from a client I would need setup and name the folder structure in a specific way. As I don't have controll over the server I was looking for a way to manage this. 
So yes, it was definently my business to "mess" with this. 
But the question is moot now as we've gone in another direction.